# How to create authentication server OKTA with my database?

Tags: java, spring-boot, okta

Currently, I working with Okta to authentication identity (SSO) using spring boot. However my client want using users from database of them. I have research with OpenID Connect but haven't result.

https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/auth-servers/

https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/add-an-external-idp/openidconnect/configure-idp-in-okta/

So, "Okta have support connect to database (MySQL) for authentication user instead of using Okta user"?.

Answer (score 0):

Users must exist within Okta in order to be granted tokens. This is because the users will need to be assigned the application in Okta in order to determine if they are authorized to access a given application.

You may want to look into [importing these users into Okta](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/users/#create-user-with-imported-hashed-password).